# C++ Socks5 Hostname resolution

Tags: c++, visual-c++, proxy, socks, tor

I use the following code to connect to a tor server running on the localhost. For some reasons this code resolves the ip and only gives tor the IP Address. So I am unable to connect to the hidden service since tor needs the DNS Name for connecting. For connecting to regular IP's all is working as expected, only for hidden service there is a problem.

What am I doing wrong? Is there something I am missing? I am using VisualStudio 2013.

Any help is highly appreciated!!

```
int fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if (fd < 0)
    return 1;
struct sockaddr_in destaddr;
destaddr.sin_addr.s_host = (unsigned char) "6esfckh37teglfi5.onion";
int dest_port = 19452;

struct sockaddr_in saddr;
saddr.sin_port = htons(9150);
saddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
saddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
int rv = connect(fd, (struct sockaddr *)&saddr, sizeof(saddr));
if (rv < SOCKET_ERROR)
    return 1;
char buf[256], *ptr;
ptr = buf;
PUT_BYTE(ptr++, 5);
PUT_BYTE(ptr++, 1);
PUT_BYTE(ptr++, 0x00);
send(fd, buf, ptr - buf, 0);
recv(fd, buf, 2, 0);
if ((buf[0] != 5) || buf[1] == 0xFF)
{
    exit(0);
}
ptr = buf;
PUT_BYTE(ptr++, 5);
PUT_BYTE(ptr++, 1);
PUT_BYTE(ptr++, 0);
PUT_BYTE(ptr++, 1);
memcpy(ptr, &destaddr.sin_addr.s_addr, sizeof(destaddr.sin_addr));
ptr += sizeof(destaddr.sin_addr);
PUT_BYTE(ptr++, dest_port >> 8);
PUT_BYTE(ptr++, dest_port & 0xFF);
send(fd, buf, ptr - buf, 0);
recv(fd, buf, 4, 0);
if (!buf[1] != 0x00)
{
    ptr = buf + 4;
    switch (buf[3]) {
    case 1:
        recv(fd, ptr, 4 + 2, 0);
        break;
    case 3:
        recv(fd, ptr, 1, 0);
        recv(fd, ptr + 1, *(unsigned char*)ptr + 2, 0);
        break;
    case 4:
        recv(fd, ptr, 16 + 2, 0);
        break;
    }
}
```

EDIT:

I corrected my code and changed addr bit to  3, still no success:

```
int dest_port = 19452;

    struct sockaddr_in saddr;
    saddr.sin_port = htons(9150);
    saddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    saddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    int rv = connect(fd, (struct sockaddr *)&saddr, sizeof(saddr));
    if (rv < SOCKET_ERROR)
        return 1;
    char buf[256], *ptr;
    ptr = buf;
    PUT_BYTE(ptr++, 5);
    PUT_BYTE(ptr++, 1);
    PUT_BYTE(ptr++, 0x00);
    send(fd, buf, ptr - buf, 0);
    recv(fd, buf, 2, 0);
    if ((buf[0] != 5) || buf[1] == 0xFF)
    {
        exit(0);
    }
    ptr = buf;
    PUT_BYTE(ptr++, 5);
    PUT_BYTE(ptr++, 1);
    PUT_BYTE(ptr++, 0);
    PUT_BYTE(ptr++, 3);
    //memcpy(ptr, &destaddr.sin_addr.s_addr, sizeof(destaddr.sin_addr));
    //ptr += sizeof(destaddr.sin_addr);
    memcpy(ptr, "22", 1);
    memcpy(ptr, "iszgnywrejvdg2nc.onion", sizeof("iszgnywrejvdg2nc.onion"));    
    PUT_BYTE(ptr++, dest_port >> 8);
    PUT_BYTE(ptr++, dest_port & 0xFF);
    send(fd, buf, ptr - buf, 0);
    recv(fd, buf, 4, 0);
    if (!buf[1] != 0x00)
    {
        ptr = buf + 4;
        switch (buf[3]) {
        case 1:
            recv(fd, ptr, 4 + 2, 0);
            break;
        case 3:
            recv(fd, ptr, 1, 0);
            recv(fd, ptr + 1, *(unsigned char*)ptr + 2, 0);
            break;
        case 4:
            recv(fd, ptr, 16 + 2, 0);
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: For MS, you need WSAStartup otherwise sockets won't work.

Comment: @cup: This isn't the whole code, it send the request to Tor/Socks5 but the request doesn't get finished (Tor is telling me Timeout).

Comment: @cup Do you have any further advices?